# Why shrinkWrap is needed?

Tags: android, dart, flutter

So why shrinkWrap is needed? I read about on offical [site](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/ScrollView/shrinkWrap.html), but i didnt understand. There's some example of lists where shrinkWrap is needed or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`shrinkWrap` is used when you don't want a GridView/ListView to fill its parent on their main axis.

This has the effects of enforcing your ListView/GridView to take the least amount of space.

A typical use-case would be when you want to display a list of lists.

Answer (score 1):

It says it on the [documentation page](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/ScrollView/shrinkWrap.html):

> If the scroll view *has **unbounded constraints** in the `scrollDirection`*, then `shrinkWrap` must be true.

If the constraints of the parent widget are bounded, you will not need `shrinkWrap` because the widget cannot expand further than the maximum width or height, but if the size is unbounded in the `scrollDirection`, the widget does not know "when to stop", i.e. it does not know of a maximum width or height in the `scrollDirection`.

If you are not sure if you parent widget provides bounded constraints, you can just *try it without `shrinkWrap`* and if it is needed, you will *see an error message*, which tells you to specify `shrinkWrap`.